# Testing if one list is contained in another

Tags: scheme

I want to make a function that compares two lists for me to know if one is contained in the other and in the end I a list of true or false 
example

```
(define L1 (list 2 4 5))
(define L2 (list 3 6 5 8 2))

(define (contain? L1 L2))


>(list true false true)


(define (contain? L1 L2)


 (cond
 [(or (empty? L1)(empty? L2)) false]
[else 
(cond 
 [(= (first L1) (first L2)) true]
[else (contain? (rest L1) (rest L2))])]))

(buscar (list 4 6) (list 1 2 4 6))
```

Try to do this but it tells me is false

Comment: Cool. Were you able to do it?

Comment: In what way? What did you try that didn't work? What, specifically, do you need help with? To be clear, we *love* specific questions; those that list attempts and the problems with those attempts.

Comment: Try to do this but it tells me is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the problem into 2 parts:

```
(define (contain-one? e lst)
  ; is element e contained in lst?
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) false]
    [(= e (first lst)) true]
    [else (contain-one? e (rest lst))]))
```

then

```
> (contain-one? 2 (list 3 6 5 8 2))
true
> (contain-one? 4 (list 3 6 5 8 2))
false
> (contain-one? 5 (list 3 6 5 8 2))
true
```

Second step, use this function with `map`:

```
(define (contain? lst1 lst2)
  (map (lambda (e) (contain-one? e lst2)) lst1))
```

then

```
> (contain? (list 2 4 5) (list 3 6 5 8 2))
'(true false true)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off. `cond` works as `if` except it can take many terms. In other languages that would be `elseif` so your code can be written:

```
(define (contain? L1 L2)  
  (cond
    [(or (empty? L1)(empty? L2)) false]     ; why should (contain? '() '()) ==> false?
    [(= (first L1) (first L2)) true]        ; stops here with one true value as result for the whole thing.
    [else (contain? (rest L1) (rest L2))])) ; recurses without makeing a pair that has a false-value and the recursion as it's tail
```

This evaluates to `true` if you find the same number at the same position in both lists. Otherwise it will evaluate to `false`.

If you want a list with `true` and `false` you need to use `(cons this-result (recurse-rest))` in the two positions wxcept ehere one list is `empty?`. When `empty?` you need to teminate the list with an empty list.

Ie. `(contain? '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1 0))` which is `(contain (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 '())))` the procedure need to do each pair (cons) at a time so that the first iteration would be `(cons false recursion-result)`, the second iteration becomes `(cons true recursion-result)` and the 4th iteration the first list is `empty?` so it evaluates to `'()`.

Your example in the beginning seems to think you should be able to make a true value if you find the current element in the first list at any position in the second. To do that you need to iterate the first list and for each element search for it in the second with `member`. eg. in the first iteration using the global L1 and L2 the expression to check if you have it cannot be `(eq? (first l1) (first l2))` but rather `(memq (first L1) L2)`